# How to fix Content Security Policy restricting my BingMap to render virtualearth Street side view?

Tags: javascript, angular, content-security-policy

I am using BingMap in my angular app. I have implemented the Content Security Policy in my index.html file to restrict the unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval code execution. I have allowed only *.bing.com and *.virtualearth.net in my script-src.

Everything works fine except the street-side view loading the virtual earth on the page. It is restricting to manipulating my page and injecting unsafe-eval and unsafe-inline scripts dynamically.

How can this be fixed and how can to render my virtual earth with CSP restrictions of unsafe-eval and unsafe-inline?